# Ubuntu 20.04 is draining battery on Dell XPS - CPU core idle state not scaling frequency

Tags: dell, power-management, battery, cpu

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest updates on a Dell XPS 9510 and battery performance is really bad. With light usage (only web browsing on simple websites) I have maximum about 1h30 of battery life while under Windows the laptop can easily reach 8 hours. The difference is massive.

I checked a lot of settings and install TLP to improve battery life without significant changes, however I observed a strange behavior that might explain this high consumption. While core are scaling properly under load when the core is in idle state, the frequency goes back to nominal speed (2,5Ghz) instead of minimum speed (800Mhz).

Here are some output:

```
    $ sudo tlp-stat -p
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Processor
CPU model      = 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900H @ 2.50GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  4900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  4900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_power [HWP.EPP]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  16 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  57 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  41

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient       = Y
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0





$paste <(ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq) <(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*) | column -s $'\t' -t
affected_cpus                             0
base_frequency                            2500000
cpuinfo_max_freq                          4800000
cpuinfo_min_freq                          800000
cpuinfo_transition_latency                0
energy_performance_available_preferences  default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
energy_performance_preference             balance_power
related_cpus                              0
scaling_available_governors               performance powersave
scaling_cur_freq                          1103306
scaling_driver                            intel_pstate
scaling_governor                          powersave
scaling_max_freq                          4800000
scaling_min_freq                          800000
scaling_setspeed                          <unsupported>

$cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^[c]pu MHz"
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 1070.651
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 1102.344
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
cpu MHz     : 2500.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^[c]pu MHz"` lists 2500.000 when a CPU is idle, it is merely a default base frequency print out because the actual CPU frequency information is stale and the kernel doesn't want to wake the sleeping CPU just to determine its operating frequency.

You could look at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` instead:

```
doug@s19:~$ uname -a
Linux s19 5.13.0-52-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 16 21:21:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800217
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800279
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800004
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800193
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800290
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800143
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:801221
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800419
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800160
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800362
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800214
```

However, it's response will be changing to the same as /proc/cpuinfo as of kernel 5.19:

```
doug@s19:~$ uname -a
Linux s19 5.19.0-rc5-stock #1072 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 4 07:58:15 PDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:799988
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800528
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
```

That being said, CPU frequency is not the way to investigate energy consumption anyhow. Often, but definitely not always, a higher CPU frequency allows a task to complete faster resulting in more time in a deep idle state concluding with less energy use. The recommended tool to use for most Intel processors (within the last decade) and, recently, some AMD procoessors power monitoring is turbostat (linux-tools-common package, I think). Example:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 15
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.01    1328    425     34      1.42    0.76    0.00    0.89
0.01    800     269     34      1.39    0.73    0.00    0.89 <<< system idle
0.01    800     291     34      1.38    0.72    0.00    0.89
0.01    800     331     34      1.37    0.70    0.00    0.89
81.14   4530    37381   68      110.03  109.37  0.00    0.89
99.05   4513    45191   67      130.44  129.78  0.00    0.89 <<< Big load
99.62   4482    45166   68      124.91  124.25  0.00    0.89 <<< Power limit throttling
99.60   4478    45209   71      124.91  124.25  0.00    0.89
99.58   4473    45171   72      124.92  124.25  0.00    0.89
37.66   4470    17655   43      48.26   47.60   0.00    0.89
0.01    800     315     42      1.52    0.86    0.00    0.89 <<< system idle
0.01    800     316     42      1.50    0.84    0.00    0.89
0.01    800     257     41      1.68    1.02    0.00    0.89
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, indeed scaling is working when core is idle. I'll have to continue my investigation on why battery is draining that fast.

Comment: Ho did your investigation go? I bought the new 9530 model (2023) and the battery drain is at 20W when idle with bluetooth and wifi off, which gives about 3h life only.

Comment: @RobDecker I think my answer should help you.

Comment: @flm I think my answer should help you (could unfortunately not tag both of you in one comment)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar poor battery life on my XPS 15 9530 (2023 model) running Ubuntu 22.04. I found this tool `powertop`, which was showing around 25 Watts of battery drain while running idle on external display (internal display off). What it was also showing is a bunch of "Tunables", including "Runtime PM for PCI Device NVIDIA Corporation Device 28a0" which apparently currently had the "bad" setting. Toggling this to the "good" setting reduced the power consumption to ~8.5 Watts! This obviously greatly improves the battery life.

Basically this setting controls power management for the GPU, which is apparently just always powered on by default.

Under the hood what this toggle does on my device is `echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control';`. Unfortunately this is does not persist through reboots. One simple way to achieve that is to edit /etc/rc.local as root (or create it if it doesn't exist, don't forget to add a shebang (#!/bin/bash) on top and chmod a+x /etc/rc.local) (ie `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`) and add this:

`echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control'`;

That should automatically enable automatic power management for the GPU on startup.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!! it worked also on my XPS 9730... quite insane, going from 4 hours of battery duration to 10 with just that